# iterate over dom elements and append each one to other elements

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, wordpress

I use a custom post on WordPress, I had an issue with the post date not displaying by default on the archive page
so I added codex code to displaying it
it worked fine but the problem is each post date displaying before the element
for example:

```html
<!-- Post 1-->
<div class=".archive-custom-post-date">02/03/2021</div>
<article>Post 1</article>

<!-- Post 2-->
<div class=".archive-custom-post-date">02/03/2021</div>
<article>Post 2</article>

<!-- Post 3-->
<div class=".archive-custom-post-date">02/02/2021</div>
<article>Post 3</article>

<!-- Post 4-->
<div class=".archive-custom-post-date">0`/03/2021</div>
<article>Post 4</article>

<!-- Post 5-->
<div class=".archive-custom-post-date">12/02/2021</div>
<article>Post 5</article>
```

so I tried to add jQuery code to iterate over each post date and append them to each post but it didn't work, they attach to the last post (all dates) only, or adding all post dates to each post for example each post will have all dates.

```js
 //@1 if I use this function it will add all post dates to each post
 function append_post_date() {
    jQuery(".archive .archive-custom-post-date").each(function (
      idx,
      date_element
    ) {
      return jQuery(date_element).appendTo(".archive article");
    });
  }


//@2 if I use this function it will added all post dates to last element on dom
function append_post_date() {
  jQuery(".archive .archive-custom-post-date").each(function (
    idx,
    date_element
  ) {
    // #2
    jQuery(".archive article").each(function (idx, article_element) {
      return jQuery(this).append(date_element);
    });
  });

  //end
}
```

Comment: Seems a lot of work for such an issue. Can't you just update the custom post type default file ?

Comment: Do you want to display the date after the `article`?

Comment: I want to display it inside each post.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can loop of `'.archive-custom-post-date'` each and append to the next `article`. check below snippet.

```js
(function($){
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('.archive-custom-post-date').each(function(){
      var dateHtml = $(this);
      $(this).next().append(dateHtml);
    });
  });
})(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Post 1-->
<div class="archive-custom-post-date">02/03/2021</div>
<article>Post 1</article>

<!-- Post 2-->
<div class="archive-custom-post-date">02/03/2021</div>
<article>Post 2</article>

<!-- Post 3-->
<div class="archive-custom-post-date">02/02/2021</div>
<article>Post 3</article>

<!-- Post 4-->
<div class="archive-custom-post-date">0`/03/2021</div>
<article>Post 4</article>

<!-- Post 5-->
<div class="archive-custom-post-date">12/02/2021</div>
<article>Post 5</article>
```

Comment: If my answer helped you then you can upvote as well.

Answer (score 0):

Solution in vanilla js

```
// iterate over all article elements on page    
document.querySelectorAll('article').forEach(article => {
    // get element before article
    const date = article.previousElementSibling;
    // remove it from dom
    date.parentElement.removeChild(date);
    // add it as first child of article
    article.prepend(date);
})
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation, including the assumptions you’ve made.